# Performance issues inserting data into PostgreSQL using JAVA

Tags: java, postgresql, sql-insert

i'm having problems inserting data into a Postgresql database. The code generates random values and inserts them into the database. It works fine if i try to insert up to 300000 rows at a time, but any higher number of rows crashes the pc for about 30 min. (same code works fine with MYSQL and SQLite inserting 1 mln rows). Is there a way to overcome this issue by fixing the code or is ti mainly a hardware problem?

```
public static void insertToTable(Connection c, String tableName, int numberOfRows) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, SQLException {
            Random rand = new Random();
            StringBuilder sql =
                    new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (NR,PIRMAS,ANTRAS,TRECIAS,KETVIRTAS,PENKTAS,SESTAS,SEPTINTAS,ASTUNTAS,DEVINTAS) VALUES ");

            for (int j = 0; j < numberOfRows; j++) {
                if (j != 0) sql.append(",");
                sql.append("(" + j +
                        ",'" + String.valueOf(rand.nextInt()) + "'" +
                        ",'" + String.valueOf(rand.nextInt()) + "'" +
                        ",'" + String.valueOf(rand.nextInt()) + "'" +
                        ",'" + String.valueOf(rand.nextInt()) + "'" +
                        ",'" + String.valueOf(rand.nextInt()) + "'" +
                        ",'" + String.valueOf(rand.nextInt()) + "'" +
                        ",'" + String.valueOf(rand.nextInt()) + "'" +
                        ",'" + String.valueOf(rand.nextInt()) + "'" +
                        ",'" + String.valueOf(rand.nextInt()) + "'" +
                        ")");


            }
```

Comment: Please learn to properly use a `PreparedStatement` do not concatenate values into a SQL string.

Comment: Better use the COPY statement. https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html